# Unable to update global token using RxJava's retryWhen operator

Tags: android, rx-java, rx-java2

My token will expire, so I want to use the retryWhen operator to automatically get the token when the token expires, refresh the token in a simple class, and retry the request. But at this time there was a problem, I got the token, but when I re-initiated the request, the token in the request was empty, but I confirmed that I got the token.

NetService

```
@GET("/meeting/api/v2.0/schedules")
fun getMySchedule(@Query("start_time") startTime: Long,
                  @Query("end_time") endTime: Long,
                  @Query("type") type: Int,
                  @Header("cookie") cookie: String = "ssoid=${MeetingTokenManager.accessToken}")
        : Observable<BaseData<List<MyScheduleResponse>>>
```

token singleton

```
object MeetingTokenManager {
    var accessToken: String = ""
}
```

TokenRefreshFun

```
class TokenRefreshFun(private val baseView: IBaseView) : Function<Observable<Throwable>, ObservableSource<*>> {
var count = 0
override fun apply(t: Observable<Throwable>): ObservableSource<*> = t.flatMap {
    if (it is NetExceptionHandler.ResponseException) {
        if (it.code == 401) {
            logi("token验证失败.开始刷新token")
            if (count == 0) {
                count++
                baseView.tokenExpired()
            } else {
                Observable.error(it)
            }
        } else {
            Observable.error(it)
        }
    } else {
        Observable.error(it)
    }
}}
```

request function

```
 fun getMySchedule(startTime: Long,
                  endTime: Long,
                  type: Int = 1) {
    mScheduleBiz.getMySchedule(startTime, endTime, type)
            .compose(RxHelper.singleModeThread(iBaseView = mMyScheduleView))
            .retryWhen(TokenRefreshFun(mMyScheduleView))
            .subscribe(KNetObserver({
                mDisposables.add(it)
            }, {
                when (it.status) {
                    1 -> mMyScheduleView.getMyScheduleSuccess(it.data)
                    0 -> mMyScheduleView.getMyScheduleFailed("获取日程失败")
                }
            }, {
                mMyScheduleView.getMyScheduleFailed(it.message)
            }))
}
```

baseView.tokenExpired()

```
fun authorization(context: Context): Observable<String> {
    return Observable.create<String> { e ->
        AuthorizationManager.authorization(context, CLIENT_ID, { token ->
            accessToken = token
            logi(accessToken)
            JTUInfoSDK.getInstance().setCookie(token)
            LoginMyInfo.accessToken = token
            e.onNext(token)
        }, {
            e.onError(Throwable(it))
        })
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You say that you received the token. I presume you mean that your logging statement showed that you received a token.

I notice, however, that `accessToken` is assigned the value of the token, so I presume it is used by your network access code. When is that value bound? I am going to guess that `getMySchedule()` binds the prior value of the token and never recomputes it.

You will have to restructure your code so that the binding of the cookie value is re-done if there is an error.